# PostgreSQL: select from field with json format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Table has column, named "config" with following content:

```
   {
     "A":{
        "B":[
              {"name":"someName","version":"someVersion"},
              {"name":"someName","version":"someVersion"}
            ]
         }
    }
```

The task is to select all name and version values. The output is expected selection with 2 columns: name and value.

I successfully select the content of B:

```
select config::json -> 'A' -> 'B' as B
from my_table;
```

But when I'm trying to do something like:

```
select config::json -> 'A' -> 'B' ->> 'name' as name,
       config::json -> 'A' -> 'B' ->> 'version' as version
from my_table;
```

I receive selection with empty-value columns

Comment: Why the `::json` cast? If that column stores JSON data it should be defined as `jsonb` or at least `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array size is fixed, you just need to tell which element of the array you want to retrieve,e.g.:

```
SELECT config->'A'->'B'->0->>'name' AS name,
       config->'A'->'B'->0->>'version' AS version
FROM my_table;
```

But as your array contains multiple elements, use the function `jsonb_array_elements` in a subquery or CTE and in the outer query parse the each element individually, e.g:

```
SELECT rec->>'name', rec->>'version'
FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(config->'A'->'B') 
      FROM my_table) j (rec);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7552f249b1c87e53d3a2252744930547)

Answer (score 1):

First you should use the jsonb data type instead of json, see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) :

> In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as
> jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy
> assumptions about ordering of object keys.

Using jsonb, you can do the following :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c) c->'name' AS name, c->'version' AS version
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(config :: jsonb, '$.** ? (exists(@.name))') AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b0497553130ccc0df09fcb7412b8a799)

```sql
select e.value ->> 'name', e.value ->> 'version'
from 
  my_table cross join json_array_elements(config::json -> 'A' -> 'B') e
```